# How can I solve this errorv - npm start - npm ERR! missing script: start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[image]

I am receiving this error when I tried to write npm start command after installing the react.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `package.json` file. It should contain the `start` entry in the `scripts` key.

Read the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples) for detailed information.

Your package.json should contain this entry:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
}
```

Replace `main.js` with the script name you are trying to run. You can test its execution by just running `node main.js` in the console and determining whether that even works.

Comment: there is no scripts key in package.json file.

Comment: {
  "name": "myreact",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.0",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  }
}

Comment: If it is a fresh react project it is likely `"start": "react-scripts start",` that is missing, but if an established project that may have changed over time depending on your needs and configuration.

Comment: @DeepGaganGuru If there is no scripts key then you can create one.